# How to convert Scanned PDF into Searchable PDF using React Js

Tags: reactjs, pdf, ocr, tesseract, jspdf

I am not able to convert scanned pdf into searchable pdf using reactjs . so is there any library to convert this or using react js was not possible? I used so many libraries which related to ocr or pdf. If there is any solution to solve this help me

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.